# Auth0 - Universal Login Custom Reset Pass

Tags: authentication, auth0

I'm trying to implement a custom reset page in Auth0 using their Universal Login system.

I managed to set up the login page, but I'm not able to find any relevant documentation regarding password reset and a specific javascript code to pass the information from my form directly trough their API.

Anyone else faced this issued and found a solution or at least a way to hack it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is [link](https://github.com/react-shop-dev/mui-auth0-form) to repo with custom auth0 form on github. It includes ChangePassword component with "resetPassword" method. Form can be viewed by running `yarn dev:pass` command.

Also see example of code for Password Reset template (step 8).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, **it's impossible to customize the reset password page** for Auth0 - Universal Login. Haven't found a solution after 4 months, searched for solutions every week